# What happens to the space in a black hole?

Tags: black-holes, spacetime, event-horizon, singularities

What's the smallest unit of space and is space static?  What happens when a black hole passes through space?  Does it escape the grips of a black hole? does it pull it with?  Is space a inseparable medium?  Ok so there's a few questions in this.  I did some research didn't find much.

Comment: You seem to be thinking of space as some kind of physical substance. May I suggest thinking more in terms of an empty vacuum?

Comment: This is a lot of different questions. The stackexchange format doesn't work well when you try to combine many different questions into one. Could you try to edit this down to a single question?

Comment: Near duplicate of [What happens to the space a black hole passes through?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/397293/what-happens-to-the-space-a-black-hole-passes-through)