# Do black holes move through space?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes

I know it was already asked here:
[Does a black hole move through space? What happens to other things around it?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/314141/) 
And it might be a very stupid question, but here it is:

From a relativistic perspective, do black holes move through space, or is it the space around them that is curved in such a way that for us they seem to move?

I know there is no absolute frame of reference in relativity, but let's say the standpoint of one blackhole, I would think time is frozen, so without time how can things move?

Comment: in your first question, it's not clear what the difference between the two possibilities is. Ultimately, a black holes *is* a configuration of curved spacetime, so a black hole moving through space is space "around it" being curved.

Comment: "*without time how can things move*" - Without time there can be no **relative** motion where time is stopped, but there can be motion relative to the areas where time is moving. This subject is discussed in depth here: [Metric of spacetime with zero speed of light](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3310040) - Specifically your question is answered there in this comment: "*With $c\to 0$, a velocity boost becomes a shear transformation preserving the timelike direction.*" - This refers to Linear Frame Dragging: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frame-dragging ("frozen" stuff moves together)

Comment: Nothing moves relative to its own frame of reference, only relative to something else’s frame of reference.

Comment: To add clarification to what this question is asking, I think OP's proposed idea/conception of his alternate idea for how a black hole "moves" might be similar to how alcubierre drives or the expansion of the universe works. So, to properly answer his question, it might be useful to explain one or both of those mechanisms and how black holes are different.

Comment: "Do penguins move through space, or is it the space around them that is curved in such a way that for us they seem to move?" The correct answer is, it depends on your frame of reference. I don't think the answer for black holes would differ much from the answer for penguins.

Answer (score 36):

Yes, they can move through space. [LIGO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LIGO) has detected [gravitational waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_wave) from multiple pairs of black holes orbiting each other, spiraling together, and merging.

Comment: While this answer is technically true, I'm not sure it actually gets at what the question is asking. It seems like the question is not asking whether a black hole changes position, but asking something like whether black hole motion is more like how a ship with an alcubierre drive would move.

Comment: @Shufflepants, yes I understood the question like you, but I would still say that is the right answer ... For an Alcubierre motion, the black hole would need as much 'negative energy' as it contains positive energy. My understanding of BH so far has them only positive.

Comment: I think the LIGO group is rather loose with what they mean by black holes to be honest from a strict GR perspective.

Answer (score 19):

Consider a black hole with lots of stuff in orbit around it. For example, most galaxies are like this (they have a big black hole at the centre, or, at least, there are good reasons to think that this is so). When all the orbiting stuff moves along together (while still orbiting), surely it makes sense to say the black hole is itself moving along too. For example, eventually one galaxy could bump into another. Indeed, this has happened many times, and with a big telescope we can see some such mergers ongoing now (or rather, at the moment the light set off towards our telescope).

Comment: I don't understand why the galaxies bumping into eachother is relevant or what it means for the answer.

Comment: @Parrotmaster - It proves the key point.  If you look at any single object from the referential frame tied to that same object, you'll be able to think that the object is never moving - instead, that the remaining objects in the universe are flying toward it, away from it, around it, sometimes crashing into it.  But if you take two objects that eventually collide and perhaps scatter or merge as a result, then there's no way how you could think of both of them as stationary in the universe.  Black holes are in no way special in this argument.

Comment: @Parrotmaster: We easily observe [many galaxies moving towards each other](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/interacting_galaxy). We're pretty sure most galaxies have a black hole in the center. Therefore, we're pretty sure many black holes move towards each other.

Comment: However as the universe is expanding one would think that a randomly-chosen pair of galaxies would be more likely to be moving away from each other than toward each other.

Comment: @padd13ear Actually the cosmic expansion is not a good example to pick, because it is more subtle, in which there is a very natural choice of coordinates in which one ascribes the increasing distances between galaxies (on a cosmic scale) not to their proper motion but rather to a change in the metric. It is better to consider collisions involving black holes, because then there is an unambiguous relative motion involved.

Comment: @padd13ear - even in the case of galaxies moving away due to expansion (or for other reasons), it would still be the case that if they contain black holes, the black holes would be moving as well. Also, cosmic expansion is about the expansion of the fabric of space itself rather than the actual motion of the galaxies (or other bodies.)

Answer (score 10):

Yes. Here is a geometric perspective.

Take e.g. the Schwarzschild metric in coordinates $x^\mu=(t,r,\phi,\theta)$:
$$
g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=-(1-r_S/r) dt^2 + (1-r_S/r)^{-1}dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta^2+ \sin^2\theta d\phi^2) \qquad \text{(Schwarzschild)}
$$
where $r_S$ is the Schwarzschild radius. The geometry as $r\to +\infty$ will look like Minkowski space in spherical coordinates (for the spacelike part):
$$
g_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu=- dt^2 +dr^2 + r^2 (d\theta^2+ \sin^2\theta d\phi^2) \qquad \text{(Minkowski)}\,.
$$
Consider changing to Cartesian coordinates $(r,\phi,\theta)\to(x,y,z)$, doing a boost (say along the $x$ direction), and changing back to spherical coordinates. The Minkowski geometry will look exactly the same.

However, doing the same for the Schwarzschild geometry will give you a different geometry! (Which I will not write down...) The new geometry corresponds to a boosted Schwarzschild black hole, one which moves at constant velocity relative to the distant observer at $r\to \infty$.

In fact, the same argument tells you that any *asymptotically flat* black hole can move relative to an observer far away from the black hole. (Of course they don't all have to move at constant speeds; it's just that one can construct constantly moving black hole geometries from the immobile ones by the above argument without actually calculating anything.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can. Everything moves in space. If you're looking for proof they can move, the Standard Model says the galaxies (which have black holes) are moving away from us. That’s a lot of black holes moving.

Comment: This answer needs way more explaining.

Comment: to be fair it is true. (except for orientifold planes I suppose)

Comment: @alexarvanitakis, "true assertion" does not mean the same thing as "good answer."

Comment: I made the answers simple just to make a point. What a ridiculous thing to argue about.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/105103/discussion-on-answer-by-bill-alsept-do-black-holes-move-through-space).